In this code, why is scanf() not setting the input to the variable properly?
I am trying to post this to the C board. If I am in the wrong place, or this is not an appropriate question please let me know so can delete or move this. Thank you very much.
I am learning C as my first programming language as I want my philosophical foundations to be based on C and how it works. I am running a test to see how scanf() works, and it is not working as I would like it to but, most importantly, I can't figure out why. If I replace scanf() with cs50's get_int it works as expected. With scanf() it says I entered 0. With get_int it displays the value entered by input.
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
// test result: scanf does not do what I want here.
int main()
{
    int num1;
    num1 = scanf("enter a number: ");
    printf("you entered %d \n", num1);
return 0;
}

This code compiles and runs, however it printf()'s 0 rather than the input that is given.
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
// test result: scanf does not do what I want here.
int main()
{
    int num1;
    num1 = get_int("enter a number: ");
    printf("you entered %d \n", num1);
return 0;
}

This code also compiles, however it prints the correct value as given by the input.
I also tried the following;
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
// test result: scanf does not do what I want here.
int main()
{
    int num1;
    num1 = scanf("enter a number: ", &num1);
    printf("you entered %d \n", num1);
return 0;
}

but it throws the following error in terminal:

test.c:7:38: error: data argument not used by format string [-Werror,-Wformat-extra-args]
7 |     num1 = scanf("enter a number: ", &num1);

I even tried casting num1 to num2 and printf() num2 but that threw an error as well.
This is just a test. I would like to understand what is happening and why it works this way. Obvs I can get it to print the proper result in such a situation, but I need to understand how scanf() works and I can't figure this out.
Again, if this is not the appropriate board for this question please let me know so I can delete or move it. I am trying to post to the C board. Thank you very much for your time, and I hope you be well and truly blessed.

Have you read anything about how to use scanf? Better not to guess with C.

Have you read the documentation for scanf()? It appears not, because it does not work the way your code assumes it does. I'd suggest that you google the documentation, so that you know where it's located in the future. You'll get a lot further if you actually learn how the code you're writing works, rather than just deciding to type it.

You're overworking variable num1.  Pls try it like this

Some documentation on scanf: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf. CS50 adds some stuff to do things differently than how C is normally used outside of that class. scanf() is input only, it does not accept a prompt to be output. It does require a format specifier to specify the nature and format of what it is to read in. You have not supplied such a specifier in your code, so it reads nothing.

SO usage note: SO is not subdivided into "C board" and other boards. All you need to do is to apply the correct tag to your question (in this case, tag [tag:c]) and then you can reach the right people.

If you want to print a prompt for the user to enter input, then you must explicitly print it to the screen before calling scanf, for example by calling printf. The CS50 function get_int will do this for you, but when using scanf, you must do this yourself.

Using scanf for reading user input is generally not recommended. You may want to read this guide for further information. In this answer of mine to another question, I have created a function get_int_from_user which works in a similar way to CS50's get_int. In my answer, I also explain why using this function is better than using scanf.

I would like to thank everyone for the information and taking the time to comment =)
I'm going to take a deeper dive into how scanf() works and what actually happens when you call the function. I think based on everything that has been said I can get it to work now, but I still want to understand what is actually going on here.

As a last update:
After reading over everything here, and prolly all of the links provided, I can't say I yet fully understand scanf(), but I am able to work with it in the way I was attempting, and various other ways as well. Perhaps over time all the little quirks and intricacies will be more plain to my understanding.

From cppreference:
int scanf( const char *restrict format, ... );

where the return value is

the number of receiving arguments successfully assigned (which may be zero in case a matching failure occurred before the first receiving argument was assigned), or EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned.

and not the input value you expect.
A correct use would be:
puts("enter a number: ");

int input_value;
int num_arg = scanf("%d", &input_value);

if (num_arg > 0) {
    printf("you entered %d number(s): %d\n", num_arg, input_value);
} else {
    puts("some error occurred");
}


The leading space in the scanf() format string is harmless but unnecessary.  The numeric conversions and string conversions all skip white space, as does the leading space.  The only scanf() conversion specifications that don't skip white space are %c, %[…] (scan sets), and %n.

Thank you for the information and taking the time to comment. I will most deff be taking a deep dive into how scanf() works and how to properly use it.

Would it be correct to say that num is the number of arguments successfully being assigned, while the &num1 is setting num1 to the value of the assigned argument?

Yes, that's right.

The issue with your code lies in the misuse of scanf():

Incorrect Format String:
scanf("enter a number: "); is invalid. scanf() expects a format specifier (e.g., %d for integers) and does not display prompts.

Missing Pointer:
scanf("%d", num1); is incorrect because num1 is not a pointer. You must pass &num1.


#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num1;
    printf("Enter a number: ");     
    if (scanf("%d", &num1) == 1)   
        printf("You entered %d\n", num1);
    else
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
    return 0;
}


I was kinda figuring scanf() doesn't display prompts (good to have that verified) and that that was only one part of the problem. Thank you for the information and taking the time to comment. =)
